# Delegating domain google dns

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, hostname

I am using NIC.ar and google cloud as host of my app, I have created a zone dns for the cloud and is like this[image: detalle de la zona]

The group of dns are the following as I understood

```
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.
```

But when I try to set this into the delegation part of Nic.ar I have the following error:

> 'ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.' is not a valid hostname

[image: error at nic.ar]

I have deleted the last ".", like this ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue, the delegation was ok, with or without the last dot, the server is found, I tested through ping and that is correct.

After that I have made a trace and it was ok, however I have a missconfiguration on google dns CNAME, it should be pointing to my domain:

```
www.blablabla.com.ar.   CNAME   300 blablabla.com.ar.
```

Sorry if my question was to basic but I didn't realize that mistake.